# Open PHP Page On Button Click

Tags: php, javascript

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I'm put together the following form contained within a PHP file.

```
<form name="savemyfindstolocation" id="savemyfindstolocation" method="post">    
            <p><label></label>
            </p>
            <p align="left">
                <input name="userid" type="text" id="userid"/>
                <input name="locationid" type="text" id="locationid"/>
                <br />
            </p>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <div align="left">Click on the map to place the marker for the find that has been made and drag until the precise location has been found. </div>
          </div>
                    <p align="left"><label>Find OSGB36 Latitude Co-ordinate<br />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <div>
                        <div align="left">
                            <input name="findosgb36lat" type="text" id="findosgb36lat" size="20" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p align="left"><label>Find OSGB36 Longitude Co-ordinate<br />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <div>
                        <div align="left">
                            <input name="findosgb36lon" type="text" id="findosgb36lon" size="20" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p align="left"><label>Date of Trip<br />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <div>
                        <div align="left">
                            <input name="dateoftrip" type="text" id="dateoftrip" size="10" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
   <input name="submit" type="submit" onclick="MM_callJS('savedata()')" value="Submit" />        
    </form>
```

It all works fine, but I'd now like to add a button that opens the following php page, 'blobupload.php'. If I've understood this correctly from the research that I've done, I need to use javascript to open the page, using the 'submit' action from the main form.

What I don't understand is how to do this when the 'submit' action is already taken for the saving of the information on the main form.

Could someone perhaps please show me how to get around this, i.e. using the same 'submit action but for two different purposes.

Comment: The form code you posted has no action attribute. How are you processing the form? If you are using PHP to processes form input you could simply redirect to your blobupload.php page at the end of the data processing. Actually, you could simply redirect regardless of how the form is processed, but you'd redirect after the processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your form tag (add the `action` attribute to file you want to load):

```
<form name="savemyfindstolocation" id="savemyfindstolocation" method="post" action="blobupload.php">
```

And you submit input tag:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to help me out with this. It works fine! Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second javascript function to open new window like this way

```
   <input name="submit" type="submit" onclick="MM_callJS('savedata()');SECOND_JS_FUNCTION()" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your suggestion. I think that I may be able to use this with another issue I've been trying to resolve. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use php to process the form is one of the way to do it.

```
<input name="submit" !!!!!!action="process.php" method="POST (or get)!!!!!!!!!! type="submit"     onclick="MM_callJS('savedata()')" value="Submit" />
```

that way the the variable will be passed to the process.php while you can also redirect the page in the process.php

```
header("Location:URL");
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking a look and replying to my post, I think this may help me with some other pages I need to put together. Kind regards.